# Getting the billable and non-billable totals for a matter through the CLIO API?

Tags: clio-api

When looking at the matter dashboard through Clio's web interface, I'm able to see there's a summary of billable, non-billable and expenses for a matter.  Can I access this information through the API?

I've looked through all of the available fields for matters.  Account balances and budgets were the closest things I could find but don't provide what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you're seeing actually come from the activities associated with the matter.  Currently, there's no direct way to get those values, but you can recalculate it from data obtainable through the API. Per [the official documentation](https://docs.developers.clio.com/api-reference/#tag/Activities) using GET requests against the following endpoints should allow you to recreate what's on the matter dashboard.

#### For Billable & Non-Billable Hours / Total:

**Make sure you specify the Matter ID you're interested in.**

```
{regional_url}/activities.json?fields=id,quantity_in_hours,total,non_billable_total&matter_id={id}&type=TimeEntry
```

The results will contain all of the time based entries associated with your matter.
It will require some processing to make sure you're adding the right values together.

- Billable Hours: Sum the `quantity_in_hours` field  for all entries
  where `"non_billable": false`
- Non-Billable Hours: Sum the
  `quantity_in_hours` field  for all entries where `"non_billable": true`
- Billable Value: Sum the `total` field.  When something
  is marked as non-billable then `"total": null`
- Non-Billable Value: Sum the `non_billable_total` field.  Just like billable value, when an entry is marked as billable then `"non_billable_total": null`

#### For Expenses:

**Make sure you specify the Matter ID you're interested in.**

```
{regional_url}/api/v4/activities.json?fields=total&matter_id={id}&type=ExpenseEntry
```

In this case, you can just sum all the values for `total` and you have your expenses.

You can get additional fields, and apply further processing if you care about was something billed or paid or so on, but this should at least get you started.